# how to run sql statement sequentially one by one by just one call

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

HI i am trying to use this code -

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["train_debConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

for creating connection string from the connection string name from the webconfig file.

i m getting this error - **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Please tell me how can i create one sql connection only by using the name of the connection string in the webconfig file.

Comment: Why not put all the code you want to run in stored proc and then call it?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to build just *one* `SqlConnection`. You should never share connections. There are resource issues involved with that. When you want a connection, build it, open it, use it, and dispose it.

Further, when using the object you need to leverage the `using` statement:

```
var cString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["train_debConnectionString"]
    .ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, c))
    {

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** if the issue is about getting to the connection string in a more concise manner, you can build a settings class on your own like this:

```
public static class AppSettings
{
    public static string ConnString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["train_debConnectionString"]
                .ConnectionString
        }
    }
}
```

and then do this:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(AppSettings.ConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, c))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: yes that is what sir, I only want to write the name of connection string only. don't want to write the whole connection string every time when i create any 'sqlconnection'

Comment: @user1366330, please see my update. I *think* it addresses what you're after.